# How to horizontal scroll in full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, fullscreen

**UPDATE:**
Got it fixed!
I ended up adding 100% to the width and height of the Div containing the table, it made the Full Screen stick perfectly to the screen allowing me too see both the scrollbars I couldn't before.
Thanks for the people who tried to help me!

I have a `div` with a `table` inside and the `div` is put into full screen mode, the `table` is big so you can't see it all in full-screen so I need the scroll functionality to work.

The vertical scroll works in full screen but not the horizontal scroll, does anybody know how to make it work with horizontal scroll in full screen mode?

This is a `ASP.NET MVC` application.

The method I use to make the `div` fullscreen:

```
    function fullscreenActivate() {
    var i = document.getElementById("overviewDiv");

    if (i.requestFullscreen) {
        i.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (i.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        i.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (i.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        i.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (i.msRequestFullscreen) {
        i.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

The `div` (table is dynamically loaded, nothing special in the `table`):

```
<div id="overviewDiv">
    Loading...
</div>
```

The `CSS` I have on the `div`:

```
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: Try by adding position relative

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood the question but: 
 1) You need to have 2 div's one parent with the screen size, 1 with the table larger then the current div
 2) You don't need js to set the parent div to full screen, you can just use width:100vw and height:100vh
 3) You can set the parent div to be overflow: scroll

In this example I set the parent width/height in px's just for better understand the result you should replace them with vh/vw.

```
.parent-div{
  background-color:red;
  /*
  Use this:
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh
  */
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.child-div{
  background:green;
  height:300px;
  width:3000px;

}
```

Hope this works for you: https://codepen.io/frivolta/pen/MXPmoe